# Is it correct to write it like that and why?

Tags: grammar

I am reading a book in which I found this sentence:
"It IS(not was) months before a father lock his daughter."
Why not write it like this : "it was months before(...)"

Comment: That sentence doesn't make sense to me with "is" *or* "was". What does "a father lock his daughter" mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fails to cite its source.

Answer (score -1):

That's because Present tense is used for describing a factual thing.

Even if the event happened before, the fact is still valid till now.
So if you are talking about some truth which was valid before and valide now and will valid in the future as well, you can still use Present tense.

For example, it is only 100 years before that many people believed 'earth is not revolving'.

Comment: I would use "was" in your example. "It *was* only 100 years before..." (Although either way it's not clear out of context: 100 years before *what*?)

Comment: This answer is replete with errors.

Comment: @nnnnnn But nothing wrong with saying *It is 500 years since people believed the earth was flat*.

Comment: @WS2 - Sure, because that's clearly in reference to present day. (Although it's not historically accurate given we've known the earth is round for *much* longer than 500 years, though some people still deny it today.)